# Clutch pedal hits floor

Tags: clutch, kia, brake-fluid, clutch-cylinder, soul

I have a Kia Soul 2011 with 140000 km on it which I bought used at 130000 km.

Since I bought it I noticed that the clutch pedal touches the floor when I press it (but it comes back up) so I checked the clutch/brake fluid level, and it was at max (so there probably isn't a leak).

So I'm wondering, is this normal for Kia Souls ?

If not, what could be causing this ?

Thank you,

Liam

Comment: Yes, it's normal as long as the clutch disengages completely. Not only for Kia Soul, but for pretty much any manual transmission car.